# How to pass variable from wp_loaded hook to custom function?

Tags: php

I'm editing `functions.php` of my theme, and I'm having trouble passing hook `$_GET` value from hook to function.

Here is the hook to get URL parameter:

```
// Get sender email via URL parameter - returns the email correctly by debug.

add_action('wp_loaded','getsender');

function getsender() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['sender'] ) ) {
        $sender = $_GET['sender'];
        return $sender;
    }

}
```

And there is the custom function that displays on the theme.

```
function ccc_my_favorite_list_custom_template( $my_favorite_post_id ) {
    

    
    /* MAIL SETTINGS */
    $to = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'test';
    
    echo '<div id="listcontainer">';
    echo 'Your List: <br/>';
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_favorite_post_id); $i++) {
        $values .= get_the_title($my_favorite_post_id[$i])."\n";
    }
    
    /* display on screen */
    echo $values;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo 'You have successfully shared with us your list! <br/> We will shortly get back to you.';
    echo '</div>';
    

    $sender = getsender();
    
    echo $sender;
    
    
    $message = "sender: ".$sender."\n list:". $values;

    /* SEND MAIL */
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
}
```

I want to pass the parameter from function `getsender()` to `ccc_my_favorite_list_custom_template()`, but the add_action hook always return true.

The reason I'm using wp_loaded hook is because he is the only one that able to receive $_GET values.

What is the correct way to pass variables from add_action hook to custom function in functions.php file?

Comment: Where/how are you calling `ccc_my_favorite_list_custom_template()`?

Comment: The code `add_action('wp_loaded','getsender');` is completely unnecessary and irrelevant to what you're trying to do, what you're doing is already correct: `$sender = getsender();`, though you've made a mistake in `getsender` as it does not return a value when `isset( $_GET['sender'] )` is false/not true

Comment: @JacobPeattie Through shortcode

Answer (score 0):

> passing hook $_GET value from hook to function.

> The reason I'm using wp_loaded hook is because he is the only one that able to receive $_GET values.

**This is not a thing.**

Hooks don't receive `$_GET` values, that's not something that happens or needs to be done. ***You can use `$_GET` anywhere.***

You can safely remove the `add_action` call, it does not help, and does not do anything. It does not need to be replaced with anything. As I mentioned before, you can use `$_GET` ***everywhere***. There are no restrictions imposed by WordPress on where it can be used, and you don't need to "recieve it" to use it, it's already there.

This was all you ever needed:

```php
$sender = getsender();
```

More accurately:

```php
$sender = $_GET['sender'];
```

It's much more likely that you used `method="post"` on a form or used POST for AJAX, or that there's been a mistake somewhere else in the code.

For example in `getsender` there's a major mistake:

```php
function getsender() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['sender'] ) ) {
        $sender = $_GET['sender'];
        return $sender;
    }
    // BUT WHAT HAPPENS HERE?!
}
```

If `$_GET['sender']` doesn't exist then the `if` statement never happens, and nothing is returned, so it'll get `null` or an empty value back and you'll never know why. It needs to return a value, even if it's a default value or an error message/value to check for.

> but the add_action hook always return true.

This is a misunderstanding of what `add_action` does. It's returning true because you told it to run the function `getsender` when the `wp_loaded` event/hook happens, and it's returning `true` for success that it encountered no problems noting that down. This does not mean that it immediatley executed your function, or that it will return the functions value, that's not what `add_action` is for. Think of it like scheduling a meeting in a calendar.

`add_action` lets you tell WP to call a function/callback when an event/hook happens with a particular name. It's useful for controlling when code runs and doing things on certain events. E.g. you could run code after a post gets saved using the `save_post` action.

It has nothing to do with retrieving variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I understand correctly I just need to use `$_GET` to get the value I need inside the custom function.

But I can't get the value from the `$_GET` because loading sequence I guess.
I need some hook to connect it.

Comment: no, you don't, `$_GET` is available at any point, there is no "connecting" needed, you can use it immediatley anywhere you want. It doesn't need to be retrieved, connected, setup, initialised, etc, PHP does that before any files are loaded, and you can use it on the very first line of the very first PHP file, all the way up until the very last line of the very last PHP file. `$_GET` is a core PHP feature not a WordPress thing and does not care which hook you use, or if you use hooks at all. Nothing is stopping you from getting the value from `$_GET`, the problem does not exist.

Comment: TLDR: You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist

Comment: my suspicion is that you've got a problem you haven't told us about and in the process of trying to figure it out you've come up with this idea and asked about that instead. I suspect it would become much clearer if you shared what you were trying to do, as well as details of when and where you're trying to use `ccc_my_favorite_list_custom_template`